# We need to get and save zend auth key to database

Tags: zend-framework, authentication

We need to get and save zend auth key to database.Please tell where to find the same and i'll store the same in database.

Answer (score 1):

Zend_Auth stores data in the session. You can get the session data to be stored in the database by using http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.savehandler.dbtable.html